# NetworkX - Collapse Graph edges based on node filter

Tags: python, graph, networkx, breadth-first-search

I have a networkx graph that I want to cut down based on the type of nodes and combine edges that don't directly connect the type of nodes I want.

For example, if I have a graph of stores and roads that looks like: Store1 -> Road1 -> Road2 -> Road3 -> Store 2

Then I want to modify the graph so we only keep the "Store" edges so the final graph looks like Store1 -> Store2. Is there a clean way to do this in NetworkX?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the nodes then use [`contracted_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_edge.html):

```
G = nx.from_edgelist([('Store1', 'Road1'),
                      ('Road1', 'Road2'),
                      ('Road2', 'Road3'),
                      ('Road3', 'Store2')],
                    create_using=nx.DiGraph)
drop = {n for n in G if n.startswith('Road')}
# {'Road1', 'Road2', 'Road3'}

for n in drop:
    G = nx.contracted_edge(G, (next(G.predecessors(n)), n),
                           self_loops=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Variant with [`contracted_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html) :

```
for n in drop:
    G = nx.contracted_nodes(G, next(G.predecessors(n)), n,
                            self_loops=False)
```

Comment: For this implementation to work beyond simple paths, all edges in the graph have to be bi-directional. Otherwise, this code fails if there is a fork. E.g., adding the edge `('Road2', 'Store3')` to the input edges only yields the following output edges: `('Store1', 'Store2'), ('Store1', 'Store3')` but not `('Store2', 'Store3')`.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen given the description of the problem (i.e. a linear path for a transporter), I think it's unlikely. But this is correct, in such case those edges should be added. Maybe OP can clarify this point and I can update the coed if needed