# Collapse edges in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

Is this really the best way to collapse edges in NetworkX?

```py
n = list(G.neighbors(node))
new_weight = G[node][n[0]]['weight'] + G[node][n[1]]['weight']

G.add_edge(n[0], n[1], weight=new_weight)

G.remove_edges_from(G[node])
G.remove_node(node)
```

It's very awkward. Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Pls reorganize your code to make it generalize for all nodes and implement in new function to call it.

Sample Func:

```
def collapse_edges(G, node):
    neighbors = list(G.neighbors(node))
    new_weight = sum(G[node][neighbor]['weight'] for neighbor in neighbors) # <= reorganize it to make it generalize

    G.add_edge(neighbors[0], neighbors[1], weight=new_weight)
    G.remove_node(node)
```

Test Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def collapse_edges(G, node):
    neighbors = list(G.neighbors(node))
    new_weight = sum(G[node][neighbor]['weight'] for neighbor in neighbors) # <= reorganize it to make it generalize

    G.add_edge(neighbors[0], neighbors[1], weight=new_weight)
    G.remove_node(node)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=2)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=3)
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=4)
G.add_edge(4, 1, weight=5)
print("Original Graph:")
print(G.edges(data=True))

node_to_collapse = 2   # <= which node to drop
collapse_edges(G, node_to_collapse)

print("\nModified Graph:")
print(G.edges(data=True))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

Before:

[image]

After (drop node2, collapse):

[image]

Comment: But that's pretty much exactly what I wrote, or? Why is this API so awkward with fake lists and fake dictionaries that are sometimes subscriptable and at other times aren't etc.

Comment: yes, I reorganized your code to run as a function. Also, there is another way: 'networkx.contracted_edge' and another example to implement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319104/6146801